# sorting multi dimensional and dynamically created arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
$feeds = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM actions WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$feeds[][$info['date']] = array("feed" => array($info['ID'] => $user_id));
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM follows WHERE user_id = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $feeds[][$info['date']] = array("follow" => $info['user_id']);
    }
```

I would like to sort that $feeds array in date format (Y-m-d H:i:s) using `[$info['date']]` key

How can i do that ?

thanks

EDIT:

example of what i want to see as result is

```
$feeds = array(
    0 => array(
       '<date>' => array("feed" => array("feed_id" => "user_id"));
    ),
    1 => array(
       '<date>' => array("follow" => "user_id" );
    ),

);
```

I want to group/sort them in DATE key and do sth depends on if it is FEED or FOLLOW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to do it in database (faster)!
But if you want do it in PHP, your need [uksort](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) (for sorting) + [foreach](http://ru.php.net/foreach) (for grouping) I think